# StaggeredLayout with FlexboxLayoutManager

Tags: android, kotlin, staggered-gridview, android-flexboxlayout

I there any way to implement a staggered layout using google's Flexbox library similar to this

[image: Layout implemented using StaggeredLayoutManager]

The above layout is created using **`StaggeredLayoutManger`** also maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

I have tried the code:

```
recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(context).apply {
            flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
            justifyContent = JustifyContent.CENTER
        }
        adapter = mAdapter
    }
```

But it's making the layout with single column and aspect ratio is also not maintained(Considering that images are of large size).

Comment: Have you tried RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager?

Comment: @Nainal There are probably a few other options. The question though is how to do this with this flexbox library, if possible

Answer (score 5):

[image]

So this is what I have done in my one project , use `FlexBoxLayout`, same in my case some pictures were very large in size , so had to do something about concurrency.

```
  flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(yourActivity.this);
  flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
  flexboxLayoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.STRETCH);
  flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
```

Main logic comes in **adapter**, on `onBindViewHolder`

```
 Glide.with(context)
         .load(String.format("yourUrlHere")
         .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
         .animate(R.anim.fadein)
         .override(dpToPx(90) ,dpToPx(90)) // here replace with your desired size.
         .centerCrop()
         .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        //  holder.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        //  holder.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
         .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
          .into(viewHolder.imageView);

   ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = viewHolder.imageView.getLayoutParams();
    if (lp instanceof FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
        FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp = (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
        Random random = new Random();
        int val = random.nextInt(5);
        if (val ==0){
            val = 1;
        }
        flexboxLp.setFlexGrow(val);
        flexboxLp.setFlexShrink(1f);

    }
```

And you can solve your problem , using this code, as i have implemented by myself in one project. Hope this solves your problem. **Happy coding** :)

**Note :** In my project depending upon requirement, I have used `flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);` so my layout is like this.

Comment: @Atif AbbAsi Can I achieve this for the below layout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395159/how-to-show-the-recyclerview-as-a-two-or-three-items-in-a-row-and-needs-to-set-o

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
alignItems = AlignItems.STRETCH
```

Instead of

```
justifyContent = JustifyContent.CENTER
```

Your new code will be like

```
recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager =FlexboxLayoutManager(context).apply {
            flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
            flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
            alignItems = AlignItems.STRETCH
        }
        adapter = mAdapter
    }
```

Comment: That has no effect. When the images are large enough they will take an entire "row" each. I fear that it's just how flexbox works.

Answer (score 0):

Its seem like you want your design like Pinterest. If you want a smooth user experience as per above image then you need to have the image height/width before loading image so that you can set the proper aspect ratio. Pinterest and other do the same way.

You need to use `GridLayoutManager` for this and using `ConstrainLayout` you can easily set the image aspect ratio like this.

```
private val set = ConstraintSet()

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val poster = mMoviePosters[position]

    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                .load(poster.imageUrl)
                .into(holder.mImgPoster)

    val ratio =String.format("%d:%d", poster.width,poster.height)
    set.clone(holder.mConstraintLayout)
    set.setDimensionRatio(holder.mImgPoster.id, ratio)
    set.applyTo(holder.mConstraintLayout)
}
```

I have already written a detail blog post about it. If you want to know more read [Aspect Ratio in Staggered LayoutManager using Constraint Layout](https://medium.com/@burhanrashid52/aspect-ratio-in-staggered-layoutmanager-using-constraint-layout-9845d04d1962)

Comment: I don't understand, does this have anything to do with `flexbox-layout`? Can this technique be used with it as well?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with `flexbox-layout`.I am trying to provide an alternate solution to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer, maybe it will help the OP, but I'm looking for a `flexbox-layout` specific solution.

Comment: Currently, I don't have a solution for `flexbox-layout`